# Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

Below I provide my code. I iterate over the DataFrame `prodRows` and for each `product_PK` I find some matching sub-list of product_PKs from `prodRows`.

```
  numRecProducts = 10
  var listOfProducts: Map[Long,Array[(Long, Int)]] = Map()
  prodRows.foreach{ row : Row =>
      val product_PK = row.get(row.fieldIndex("product_PK")).toString.toLong
      val gender = row.get(row.fieldIndex("gender_PK")).toString
      val selection = prodRows.filter($"gender_PK" === gender || $"gender_PK" === "UNISEX").limit(numRecProducts).select($"product_PK")
      var productList: Array[(Long, Int)] = Array()
      if (!selection.rdd.isEmpty()) {
        productList = selection.rdd.map(x => (x(0).toString.toLong,1)).collect()
      }
    listOfProducts = listOfProducts + (product_PK -> productList)
  }
```

But when I execute it, it gives me the following error. It looks like `selection` is empty in some iterations. However, I do not understand how can I handle this error:

```
Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1690)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1678)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1677)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1677)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:855)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:855)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:855)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1905)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1860)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1849)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:671)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2022)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2043)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2062)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2087)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(RDD.scala:918)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(RDD.scala:916)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:362)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.foreach(RDD.scala:916)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply$mcV$sp(Dataset.scala:2325)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2325)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2325)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:65)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withNewExecutionId(Dataset.scala:2823)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.foreach(Dataset.scala:2324)
    at org.test.ComputeNumSim.run(ComputeNumSim.scala:69)
    at org.test.ComputeNumSimRunner$.main(ComputeNumSimRunner.scala:19)
    at org.test.ComputeNumSimRunner.main(ComputeNumSimRunner.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$$anon$2.run(ApplicationMaster.scala:635)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.<init>(Dataset.scala:170)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$.apply(Dataset.scala:61)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withTypedPlan(Dataset.scala:2877)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.filter(Dataset.scala:1304)
    at org.test.ComputeNumSim$$anonfun$run$1.apply(ComputeNumSim.scala:74)
    at org.test.ComputeNumSim$$anonfun$run$1.apply(ComputeNumSim.scala:69)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:893)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1336)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreach$1$$anonfun$apply$28.apply(RDD.scala:918)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreach$1$$anonfun$apply$28.apply(RDD.scala:918)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:2062)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:2062)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:335)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
```

What does it mean and how can I handle it?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You cannot access any of Spark's "driver-side" abstractions (RDDs, DataFrames, Datasets, SparkSession...) from within a function passed on to one of Spark's DataFrame/RDD transformations. You also cannot update driver-side mutable objects from within these functions.

In your case - you're trying to use `prodRows` and `selection` (both are DataFrames) within a function passed to `DataFrame.foreach`. You're also trying to *update* `listOfProducts` (a local driver-side variable) from within that same function.

**Why?**

- DataFrames, RDDs, and SparkSession only exist on your Driver application. They serve as a "handle" to access data distributed over the cluster of worker machines.
- Functions passed to RDD/DataFrame transformations get *serialized* and sent to that cluster, to be executed on the data partitions on each of the worker machines. When the serialized DataFrames/RDDs get deserialized on those machines - they are useless, they can't still represent the data on the cluster as they are just hollow copies of the ones created on the driver application, which actually maintains a *connection* to the cluster machines
- For the same reason, attempting to update driver-side variables will fail: the variables (starting out as empty, in most cases) will be serialized, deserialized on each of the workers, get updated locally on the workers, and stay there... the original driver-side variable will remain unchanged

**How can you solve this?**
When working with Spark, especially with DataFrames, you should try to avoid "iteration" over the data, and use DataFrame's declarative operations instead. In most cases, when you want to reference data of *another* DataFrame for each record in your DataFrame, you'd want to use `join` to create a new DataFrame with records combining data from the two DataFrames.

In this specific case, here's a *roughly* equivalent solution that does what you're trying to do, if I managed to conclude it correctly. Try to use this and read the DataFrame documentation to figure out the details:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import spark.implicits._

val numRecProducts = 10

val result = prodRows.as("left")
  // self-join by gender:
  .join(prodRows.as("right"), $"left.gender_PK" === $"right.gender_PK" || $"right.gender_PK" === "UNISEX")
  // limit to 10 results per record:
  .withColumn("rn", row_number().over(Window.partitionBy($"left.product_PK").orderBy($"right.product_PK")))
  .filter($"rn" <= numRecProducts).drop($"rn")
  // group and collect_list to create products column:
  .groupBy($"left.product_PK" as "product_PK")
  .agg(collect_list(struct($"right.product_PK", lit(1))) as "products")
```

Comment: What if, in the function, I want to do a new query based on a row value?

Comment: @FEST you can't. You should either model that "new query per value" as a JOIN, or - if the first query results are small enough, you can *collect* the results and iterate over them on the Driver side (i.e. over a simple List, not an RDD/DataFrame) - but that's usually not recommended as it would be much slower (Spark works better with one big query vs. multiple small ones, as there's some overhead per job).

Comment: Then i'm not sure how to do my thing :(. Anyway, Thank you @Tzar Zohar

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that you try to access `prodRows` from within `prodRows.foreach`. You cannot use a dataframe within a transformation, dataframes only exist on the driver.