# sc.parallelize loses previously constructed DF

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I convert a dir listing from hdfs into an array of IDS. Next I query MySQL to create a DataFrame. When iterating over the array of IDS I pass the DF to a method that I use to create a Map of supplemental values needed for a future processing. However, if I paralellize the Array the jobs are lost and fail when I call the DF. Why?

Below is some sample code. It simplifies my problem some, but it best illustrates the issue. If I remove `sc.paralelleize` and go for `ids.map` it functions, however, my next operation (not listed) that runs in a `mapPartitions` is not available.

```
def main(args: Array[String]) {
  val ids = getIds(hdfsPath)
  val idInfoDf = idInfoDf(sparkSession)
  idInfoDf.cache()

  sc.paralleize(ids).map(id => prepare(ss,id,idInfoDf)).foreach(println(_))

}

def prepare(ss: SparkSession, id: String, df: DataFrame): Map[String, String] = {
  import ss.implicits._
  val row = df.select($"term",$"region")
              .where($"id" === id.toUpperCase())

  row.collect.map(r => Map[String,String](
    "term" -> r.getAs[String](0),
    "region" -> r.getAs[String](1))).head
}
```

additionally, I am also new to working with scala and spark. It is an exciting language, but I am also not adverse to suggestions to improve code quality.

An example of the returned error:

> ERROR TaskSetManager: Task 12 in stage 1.0 failed 4 times; aborting
>   job Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job
>   aborted due to stage failure: Task 12 in stage 1.0 failed 4 times,
>   most recent failure: Lost task 12.3 in stage 1.0 (TID 52,
>   192.168.10.196, executor 0): java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/47358940/5344058 - you cannot reference DataFrames/RDDs within transformations on DataFrames/RDD

Comment: @TzachZohar The solution to my problem is still not clear. Surely it will be after a bit of pondering and rereading. But thank you! this is the sort of  answer I have been trying to search for all afternoon.

Comment: There are many similar answers but they are indeed _very_ hard to search for (the question is rarely "why can't I use DataFrame in a DataFrame" - if askers new to ask this, they would have actually known the answer...). Good luck!

Comment: The previous comments about not being legal to use DataFrames from within transformations are correct, of course. You want to dump the entire mysql table, then do a reduceByKey instead.