# Spark 2.0 create data frame from foreach

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

Is it possible to execute foreach on a dataframe so that I can return a dataset?  I have a requirement that can only be satisfied by processing the records in order, so I am using foreach over the dataframe, but I need to create a new dataset from the result so I can write it into a parquet output file.  This pseudo-code is what I would like to accomplish:

```
dataframe.foreachPartition(
  it => {
  /// process records . . .
  /// write the results form this partition into a file for aggregation later
      sparkSession.write . . .
  }
);
// read a dataframe containing all the data sets written by the tasks
sparkSession.read . . .
```

I know that is pretty sparse, but that summarizes what I need to do.  The call to sparkSession.write is not allowed inside the foreach so I am wondering if there is another way.

Comment: Hi @absmiths did you do any progress on your research about this?

Comment: I ended up using window functions instead.  They aren't direct replacements for iterating over the rows but they go a long way and perform well if you align them with your data frame properly.

Answer (score 1):

Actually you don't have access to dataframes or datasets within foreachPartition and that's because datasets and dataframes likewise other spark entities as session are available only from the driver code.

Although one alternative would be to generate the parquet files directly using Hadoop API within foreachPartition since the data of your partition is accessible:

```
dfB.repartition(2).foreachPartition( iter => {
        iter.foreach(i => println(i))
    })
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47358177/caused-by-java-lang-nullpointerexception-at-org-apache-spark-sql-dataset?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) another thread that describes this issue and its solution in depth

Good luck