# How to open a file in the rdd having path to this file?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I am working with sentinel images data on apache spark using Scala. 
At some step I filter metadata that contains specific location and for those data I want to open new file located in subfolder.

Filter rdd contains key as path to file with globalmetadata and  value as path to file which I would like to open.

```
var global_and_cloud=global_filter.map{case(name, positions_list, granule)=>
(name, (name.substring(0, name.length-14)+granule.substring(13,56)+"QI_DATA/MSK_CLOUDS_B00.gml"))}
```

The best I can do is

```
var global_and_cloud2=global_and_cloud.map{case(name, cloud_path)=>
(sc.wholeTextFiles(cloud_path).first._1, sc.wholeTextFiles(cloud_path).first._2)}
```

but it's throwing exeptions java.lang.NullPointerException when I want to take action on it,

and when I do

```
sc.wholeTextFiles(global_and_cloud.first._2).first._2
```

i get a content of file so it's exist

Is there any way to read a file inside rdd?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use any of Spark's driver-side abstractions (`SparkSession`, `RDD`, `DataFrame` etc.) within any function used to operate on an RDD's data (i.e. functions passed to `RDD.map`, `RDD.filter` etc.) - see full explanation here: [Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47358177/caused-by-java-lang-nullpointerexception-at-org-apache-spark-sql-dataset).

You'll have to `collect()` the `global_and_cloud` RDD, which would create a local array (in driver application's memory) of file names, which you can then map into an Array of file names and the RDD holding that file's data, something like:

```
val files: Array[(String, String)] = global_and_cloud.collect()

// since "files" is a "local" array and not an RDD - we can use 
// "sc" when mapping its values:
val rdds: Array[(String, RDD[String])] = files.map {
  case(name, cloud_path) => (name, sc.textFile(cloud_path))
}
```

NOTE that if `global_and_cloud` is too large to be collected into local memory, this might cause slowness or `OutOfMemoryError`. But that would mean you're trying to "open" millions of files, which would fail anyway (would require too much Driver memory to hold that many RDDs).

Comment: Glad it did! To show the community that this solved your issue, feel free to Accept the answer.